# PowerPoint VBA pass BUILT IN enumeration value to function

Tags: vba, constants, parameter-passing, powerpoint, enumeration

I'm building a ribbon tab and several of the buttons insert textboxes (each with differing formats).

I have built a 'CreateTextBox' function that takes as input parameters (i) the active slide, (ii) box width, (iii) box height this works fine

I want to add a fourth parameter which is whether or not it should auto-size (so a PpAutoSize constant):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textframe.autosize

Example of how this would play out is a line in the sub that links to the button being:

```
Set NewTextBox = CreateTextBox(CurrentSlide, 200, 100, ppAutoSizeNone)
```

But, nothing I've tried allows me to pass that constant in a way that it could be picked up like this in the function CreateTextBox:

```
Function CreateTextBox(sld As Slide, tbWidth As Double, tbHeight As Double, AutoSizeConstant as ???????) as Shape
    Set CreateTextBox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(.........)   
    With CreateTextBox
        ...
        ...
        .TextFrame.AutoSize = AutoSizeConstant
    End With
End Function
```

Everything I can find talks about creating a custom enumeration and passing the index of the item you want. I don't want to duplicate anything or have to use class modules, just want to pass the constant per the above.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to use 'ByVal AutosizeConstant as PpAutoSize'. If all goes well then you should get the list of the three autosize constants when you come to enter this value in a the function call.  In case of doubt you can use the object browser to check if the PpAutoSize enumeration exists in the Powerpoint object modes (which it does).

Answer (score 0):

Per comment from freeflow, you can specify the enumeration as the type so 'ByVal AutosizeConstant as PpAutoSize' works. Thank you!